# How do I convert this standard sql to legacy sql code in bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION
  s2id(lit FLOAT64,
    low FLOAT64,
    level FLOAT64)
  RETURNS STRING
  LANGUAGE js AS """
return litLowToId(lit,low,level);
"""
OPTIONS
  (library="test.js");
```

Big query is highlighting the `lit` part without telling me why. It just says `encountered "" in line 2`. What is happening here?

Comment: Are you sure it's visual line 2 and not BQ's line 2? It looks like the issue lies in `"""return litLowToId(lit,low,level);"""`

Comment: What's the difference between the two you mentioned? I would think it's bigquery's line 2 but it should be the same.

Comment: Visual line 2 is the second line of the code as typed. BQ's line 2 is the second line of code processed. If memory serves, BQ formats code as part of processing, which means that what you see as line 2,3,4 and 5 is actually part of line 1.

Comment: why do you need to convert it to legacy SQL?

Answer (score 1):

> Big query is highlighting the lit part without telling me why. It just says encountered "" in line 2. What is happening here?

The reason you are getting above error in UI is because you are using Legacy SQL
Switch to Standard SQL (uncheck `Use Legacy SQL` checkbox in Options Panel [in Classic UI] or check `Standard SQL` dialect radiobox [in new UI] ) 
Alternatively you can just add below line to the very top (as a first line) of your whole code
See [`Enabling Standard SQL`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#enabling_standard_sql) for more details

```
#standardSQL
```

In addition you have to provided a valid path - something like below

```
library="gs://my-bucket/path/to/test.js"
```

And finally, you need to have actual query below your function

> How do I convert this standard sql to legacy sql code in bigquery?

I strongly recommend you to stay with BigQuery Standard SQL
In case you you locked by existing legacy sql code - you might rather want to migrate your sql query from legacy to standard instead

In any case UDF for BigQuery legacy and standard dialect are quite different  - see [`Differences in user-defined JavaScript functions`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#differences_in_user-defined_javascript_functions)